# How to override SonataBasketBundle vendor views

Tags: symfony, sonata

just a little question:
I have a vendor bundle e.g. SonataBasketBundle with some views.
I extended it by SonataEasyExtend in my `src/Application/SonataBasketBundle` folder.
PROBLEM: I would to override vendor views, and I use the classical two methods: copy all views files in `src/Application/SonataBasketBundle/Resources/views` or copy them in `app/Resources/SonataBasketBundle/views`.
But, unfortunately, both methods do not works. What's the possible problem?
I missed some configuration?

I made a little test:
my extended bundle is named "ApplicationSonataBasketBundle".
Now, if in the vendor basket index method, I change the view name this way

```
return $this->render('ApplicationSonataBasketBundle:Basket:index.html.twig',
                array(
                'basket' => $this->get('sonata.basket'),
                'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
```

the framework load the application bundle view, as I want.
But, if the application bundle extends the vendor one (SonataBasketBundle), doesn't should be loaded by default also with name SonataBasketBundle?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you empty the cache ?

Comment: Yes, as usually.
But the strange thing is that for certain bundle this mechanism works, not for others.

Comment: What's the full route of the bundle views, and yours?

Comment: My first override test was on SonataBasketBundle:Basket:index.html.twig view, corresponding to the route /app_dev.php/shop/basket/

Answer (score 0):

Override view file by pasting correct view files in

> app/Resources/bundle/views

then clearing cache afterward by console

> php app/console ca:cl

or delete cache files manually from app/cache (Better)

[symfony doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_templates.html)

when overriding child bundle, it is good to override the controllers as well as the templates

```
<?php
// src/Acme/UserBundle/AcmeUserBundle.php

namespace Acme\UserBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AcmeUserBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```